# UK Tier2 ICT resignation query

Tags: uk-visa

I am in UK on a Tier 2 ICT (Intra company transfer) visa ? I need to resign and after the last working day until I leave UK, how much time do I have in between? I mean, after last working day how long can I stay in UK for rest of the travel preparation, completing services contracts etc. I cannot see a confirmed statement. I have booked the tickets a week after my last working day and my visa is valid until next year (which will obviously become invalid after curtailment period).

Do I need to leave the very next day of my last working day with my employer in UK?

Answer (score -1):

Pending a definitive answer, consider asking your employer to make your last contracted day the day before you leave, but take annual leave (vacation time) during your final week.